# How to limit regenerative braking charge current into 48 V DC Battery?

Tags: battery-charging, dc-motor, current-limiting

I have a 48 V DC battery which supplies more or less constant current (70 A) to the motors. When the motion direction is reversed, the motors start working as generators and the battery is being charged with the current reaching around 30 A. How can I limit this charging (recuperating) current to a lower value?

Comment: If I correctly understand, these 30 A are already the excessive current that charges the battery. The system that I am talking about is basically a lift that transports the load up and down along the rail. So, while going down, the motors use part of the generated energy to keep the low constant speed and this excessive current (30 A) flows to the battery and charges it. Which means, yes, if possible, a part of this current should be used for dynamic braking of the motors. However, I will appreciate any ideas regarding this matter.

Comment: Use a more suitable motor controller with soft start capability and an external resistor bank for braking.  This is not an on-topic *design* question but rather in practical terms an off-topic question on the *usage* or *purchase selection* of a motor controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the motor to be dynamically braked by this recuperating current, then you cannot simply block it with a series diode, you must divert it away from the batteries.

Put a circuit across the batteries that draws current to limit the current into them. Perhaps use a Hall sensor on the battery cable to detect the current, and control the electronic shunt to limit the charging current. If this shunt is going to dissipate 20 A at 48 V (about 1 kW), it's going to get hot, fast, so must be power rated accordingly.

There are several possible ways to make and control this shunt, depending on how much energy is going to be dumped into it. If the 1 kW load lasts only a few seconds, and isn't repeated for minutes, then you could use pulse-rated resistors, and allow them to cool between operations, as the average power is very low. If the 1 kW load continues for minutes, or is repeated often, then you need to be able to get all of that heat away in real time.

A favourite 'power resistor' of mine is the incandescent lamp. They can operate at high temperature, so have good volumetric efficiency, and are self-indicating. Due to their positive temperature coefficient of resistance, they tend to a more constant current characteristic as the supply voltage varies than a resistor would be, which is an advantage in some cases, but maybe not here, as the voltage is more or less constant around 48 V. Ceramic cased or metal jacketed power resistors might be preferable. How much you have to spend on them depends on your expected average power dissipation.

For this sort of service where the exact load current drawn does not matter too much, it's easier to have your load as several small loads, and switch them in and out with transistors. This means the transistors would dissipate very little power, with FETs you may not even need heatsinks for them.

Comment: Do you have in mind an example of such an electronic shunt?

Comment: @Chanski added to answer

Comment: This kind of shunt resistor could help you : https://www.roboteq.com/products/power-managment/shunt-regulators/sr5k100v25r-detail.

Comment: @MathieuG.  '5 kW of energy' - hmm, not written by an engineer, however, it looks like it will absorb 5 kJ of energy at a maximum power of 5 kW. The overheat shutdown will protect it! I wonder if we'd prefer that it dies protecting the expensive batteries if the nasty stuff hits the fan? And it's not really a shunt resistor, it's the whole shunt+controller circuit. It won't do a lot at 48 V though. It illustrates the main points in my answer quite well.

Answer (score -1):

The current is always controlled by the deceleration in your controller which is proportional to force.  If your voltage rises too high that is an indication of high ESR in batteries.